# ContextAPI not working in NextJS as expected extending it to other components as buttons or inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

I have a school project were I need to use NextJS, in certain point I needed to use ContextAPI to manage some things as inputs, auths and decorative elements with buttons but every single use I cannot make it work, frustrated  I made an example with basic elements following a tutorial but it didn't work, if you have suggestions, recommendations or solutions please make me know... i'm still a little frog in this.

Here's the example with basic elements:

Panel:

```
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './panel.css';

import Cajauno from './components/cajas';
import Cajados from './components/cajas2';

import { CambiarPanelCX } from './contexts/cambiarpanel';

function Panel() {
    const [showCaja, setShowCaja] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <div class="displaycajas">
                <CambiarPanelCX.Provider value={{ setShowCaja }}>
                    {showCaja ? <Cajados /> : <Cajauno />}
                </CambiarPanelCX.Provider>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Panel;
```

Boxes:

```
import './cajas.css';


function Cajados() {
    return (
        <>
        <div class="cj2">
            Hola2
        </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Cajados;
```

```
import './cajas.css';

function Cajauno() {
    return (
        <>
        <div class="cj1">
            Hola1
        </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Cajauno;
```

Panel w/button:

```
'use client';

import React, { useContext } from 'react';

import './panel.css';

import { CambiarPanelCX } from './contexts/cambiarpanel';

function Panelbtn() {
    const { setShowCaja } = useContext(CambiarPanelCX);

    return (

        <>
            <div class="displaycajabtn">
                <button 
                    onClick={setShowCaja}
                >
                    Click me
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Panelbtn;
```

Context:

```
import  { createContext } from 'react';

export const CambiarPanelCX = createContext({});
```

Main page:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

import './deco.css';
//Components
import Panel from '../../panel';
import Panelbtn from '@/src/panelbtn';

export default function PrincipalP() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Nose</title>
      </Head>
      <Panel />
      <Panelbtn />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your `Panelbtn` is outside of `Panel` and therefore, outside of the context provider's boundary.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to extend the context to other components... thx. Phil

Comment: There is not. Context by its very definition is hierarchical

Comment: Humm... I see... i think maybe I need to change the strategy to make calls for other components or found a way to make it more "accessible" to code it if that's the word.
Thanks Phil

Comment: Move the provider up to **wrap** any elements needing the context

Comment: Like the "Main Page"? if i'm understanding well